# What is the purpose of Flash's crossdomain.xml protection?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, cross-domain

If you want to use content on another server, that server needs to host a crossdomain.xml file allowing access.  If this file isn't there, flash won't let you access it.  Given that it's easy enough to just write a proxy (say a php script that curls the external URLs) what is the purpose of this restriction?  It seems that the content is still 100% available to external people, but there is just one extra hoop to jump through.  What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Flash just did the request flat out without asking for permission first it would be possible to do what is called [Cross site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

It basically means that since the request is coming from *your* computer, it will come with *your* cookies. So by accessing a known url, say gmail, I could pretend to be you. And since it's all well hidden within a .swf you'd never know what happened.

However, if the request goes through a proxy on another server (normally the same server that is hosting the swf) none of those cookies will be present and everything is nice and safe.

Comment: Ah i was looking at this from the wrong angle.  I was under the impression this would allow content owners to protect their content.  I see now it's to block all cross-site requests except the ones specifically allowed by the domain owner.

Answer (score 0):

crossdomain.xml was introduced to prevent attacks such as [Cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and also [DNS rebinding attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dns_rebinding).